# Using multiple conditions using if in sql statement

Tags: sql

How do I check multiple conditions using an if statement in sql

In pseudocode

```
If survey_field is 1 and emp_code_field = 1 and post_field = 1 THEN set chance to 10
else if survey_field is 1 and emp_code_field = 1  THEN set chance to 5
survey_field is 1 THEN set chance to 1
```

I have tried the following but I am not able to use multiple conditions .

```
Update employee 
SET chance = 
CASE survey
WHEN 1  THEN 1

END

WHERE 1
```

Comment: which database is this? mysql directly supports an `if()` statement, and most any decent sql DB does `case`.

Comment: Removing PHP since it is not relevant to this question. OP, add the database you are using as a tag - I am assuming it is MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this..

```
 UPDATE employee 
    SET chance = Case when
    ( survey_field=1) AND (emp_code_field = 1) AND (post_field = 1) THEN 10
    ELSE 
    WHEN (survey_field =1) AND (emp_code_field = 1)  THEN 5
    ELSE
    WHEN
    survey_field = 1 THEN  1
    END
```